# Java Memory Model: a JLS statement about sequential consistency seems incorrect

Tags: java, java-memory-model, jls

I'm reading [Chapter 17. Threads and Locks of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html) and the following statement about sequential consistency in Java seems incorrect to me:

> If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

They define a data race as:

> When a program contains two conflicting accesses (§17.4.1) that are not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a data race.

They define conflicted accesses as:

> Two accesses to (reads of or writes to) the same variable are said to be conflicting if at least one of the accesses is a write.

And finally they have following about happens-before relationship:

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

My problem with the 1st statement is that I think I can come up with a Java program which has no data races and allows sequentially inconsistent executions:

```java
// Shared code
volatile int vv = 0;
int v1 = 0;
int v2 = 0;


// Thread1       Thread2
   v1 = 1;
   v2 = 2;
   vv = 10;      while(vv == 0) {;}
                 int r1 = v1;
                 int r2 = v2;
                 System.out.println("v1=" + r1 + " v2=" + r2);
   v1 = 3;
   v2 = 4;
   vv = 20;
```

In the code above I also showed with indentation how the threads' code is interleaved in runtime.

So, as I understand, this program:

- has no data races: reads of v1 and v2 in Thread2 are synchronized-with writes in Thread1
- can output `v1=1 v2=4` (which violates sequential consistency).

As a result, the initial statement from JLS

> If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

seems incorrect to me.

Am I missing something or did I make a mistake somewhere?

**EDIT:** user [chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) correctly pointed out that the code I gave can output `v1=1 v2=4` with sequential consistency — the lines in threads' code simply should be interleaved a little bit differently.

So here is the slightly modified code (I've changed the order of reads) for which sequential consistency cannot output `v1=1 v2=4`, but everything still applies.

```java
// Shared code
volatile int vv = 0;
int v1 = 0;
int v2 = 0;


// Thread1       Thread2
   v1 = 1;
   v2 = 2;
   vv = 10;      while(vv == 0) {;}
                 int r2 = v2;
                 int r1 = v1;
                 System.out.println("v1=" + r1 + " v2=" + r2);
   v1 = 3;
   v2 = 4;
   vv = 20;
```

Comment: How do you know how the executions of the threads are interleaved at runtime?

Comment: Do you mean in the code examples above? I just gave one of the possible executions as an example.
The point of the code example is that it contradicts the Java Language Spec: it fits their criteria of "sequentially consistent", but allows executions which violate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is in bullet point #1: The reads of `v1` and `v2` *are not* *synchronized-with*.

There are *happens-before* relationships created *only* by the interactions with `vv`, so for example in this case, if you added `vv` to the beginning of your print statement, you would be guaranteed not to see `vv=20,v2=4`. Since you busy-wait on `vv` becoming nonzero *but then don't interact with it again*, the only guarantee is that you will see all of the effects that happened before it became nonzero (the assignments of 1 and 2). You *may also* see future effects, because you don't have any further *happens-befores*.

*Even if* you declare all of the variables as volatile, it is still possible for you to output `v1=1,v2=4` *because the multithreaded accesses of the variables do not have a defined order*, and the global sequence can go like this:

1. T1: write `v1=1`
2. T1: write `v2=2`
3. T1: write `vv=10` (Thread 2 *cannot* exit the while loop before here and is guaranteed to see all of these effects.)
4. T2: read `vv=10`
5. T2: read `v1=1`
6. T1: write `v1=3`
7. T1: write `v2=4`
8. T2: read `v2=4`

After each of these steps, the memory model guarantees that all threads will see the same values of the volatile variables, but you have a data race, and that is *because the accesses are not atomic (grouped)*. In order to assure that you see them in a group, you need to use some other means, such as executing in a `synchronized` block or putting all of the values into a record class and using `volatile` or `AtomicReference` to swap out the entire record.

Formally, the data race as defined by the JLS consists of the operations T1(write v1=3) and T2(read v1) (and a second data race on v2). These are *conflicting accesses* (because the T1 access is a write), but while both of these events happen after T2(read vv), they are not ordered *in relation to each other*.

Comment: I edited my question — I appended to the end a slightly modified version of the code (I changed the order of reads in Thread2), and now it shouldn't be possible to see `v1=1 v2=4` even if I declare all of the variables as volatile.

Comment: I think I understand your explanations and agree with almost everything. But it looks like your definition of data race differs from the definition in JLS. And I would like to understand what they mean in JLS — because it is the spec that all java implementations must conform to.

Comment: @JavaCur Updated to explicitly identify the access operations that constitute the data race.

Comment: _...which is not a defined term..._ you mean [besides the ones here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)?

Comment: @Eugene I have read the entire JLS for multiple versions of Java and have no idea how I forgot the relation is in fact defined. (The actions in question still are not related.)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually much easier to prove you are wrong than you think. Actions between two independent threads are "synchronized-with" under very special rules, all of them defined in the proper [chapter in the JSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4). The accepted answer says that `synchronizes-with` is not an actual term, but that is wrong. (unless I miss-understood the intent or there is a mistake in it).

Since you have no such special actions to establish the synchronized-with order (`SW` for short), between `Thread1` and `Thread2`, everything that follows falls like a castle of cards and makes no sense anymore.

You mention `volatile`, but be careful at the same time what `subsequent` means in that:

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

It means a read that *will observe* the write.

---

If you change your code and establish a `synchronizes-with` relationship and implicitly thus a `happens-before` like so:

```
  v1 = 1;
  v2 = 2;
  vv = 10; 

             if(vv == 10) {
                int r1 = v1;
                int r2 = v2;
                // What are you allowed to see here?
             }
```

You can start reasoning of what it is possible to be seen inside the if block. You start simple, [from here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

OK, so `v1 = 1` `happens-before` `v2 = 2` and `happens-before` `vv = 10`. This way we establish `hb` between actions *in the same thread*.

We can "sync" different threads via `synchronizes-with` order, via [the proper chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) and the proper rule:

> A write to a volatile variable v **synchronizes-with** all subsequent reads of v by any thread

This way we have established a `SW` order between two independent threads. This, in turn, allows us to build a `HB` (happens before) now, because of the [proper chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) and yet another proper rule:

> If an action x **synchronizes-with** a following action y, then we also have **hb(x, y)**.

So now you have a chain:

```
        (HB)          (HB)            (HB)                (HB)
v1 = 1 -----> v2 = 2 -----> vv = 10 ------> if(vv == 10) -----> r1 = v1 ....
```

So only now, you have proof that that if block will read `r1 = 1` and `r2 = 2`. And because `volatile` offers sequential consistency (no data races), every thread that will read `vv` to be `10` will, for sure, also read `v1` to be `1` and `v2` to be `2`.