# Should a variable be volatile between 2 running threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Should `int a` in this case be volatile to guarantee visibilty between threads?

```
private volatile static int a = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            a = 10;
        }
    });

    
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    });
    
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    
}
```

Output

```
10
```

Comment: 1) do you know which thread starts first? (hint: you don't) 2) `volatile` is about two entities - when some write is _seen_ by some other thread, it means the `happens-before` is established...

Comment: Could you explain yourself a bit further on "happens-before"? And you didn't really answer if in this case the volatile keyword is needed.

Comment: The problem is that this level it is very difficult to know the basics and apply it correctly. But in this case making a volatile would do the trick (it establishes the happens before relation as Eugene already pointed out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you explain yourself a bit further on "happens-before"?

The most important thing to remember about "happens before" is that it's a [*transitive relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). That means, if the Java Language Spec (JLS) promises that A "happens before" B, and it promises that B "happens before" C, then you can infer a promise that A "happens before" C.

The JLS says that a write to some `volatile` variable "happens before" a subsequent read of the same variable.

Well Duh! Sounds obvious, doesn't it?

But it's *not* obvious because the JLS does *not* give the same guarantee for a non-volatile variable.  If processor A writes the value 7 to a non-volatile int, and then some time later processor B writes 5, the JLS does not guarantee that some long time later, the final value of the variable will be 5.  Processor B will see 5 (that's a different "happens before" promise, see below). Processor A could see 5 or 7, and any other processor could see 5 or 7 or whatever value the variable had initially (e.g., 0).

**How the `volatile` promise helps**

Suppose we have

```
 volatile boolean flag = false;
 /*non-volatile*/ int i = 0;
```

Suppose thread A does this:

```
i = 7;
flag = true;
```

And suppose thread B does this:

```
if (flag) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Bleah!");
}
```

Thread B could print "7", or it could print "Bleah!" but because of the "happens before" guarantee, we absolutely know that thread B will never print "0".  Why not?

Thread A set `i = 7` before it set `flag = true`. The JLS guarantees that if a single thread executes one statement before it executes a second statement, then the first statment "happens before" the second statement. (That sounds *stupendously* obvious, but again, it shouldn't. A lot of things having to do with threads are *not* obvious.)

Thread B tests `flag` before it prints `i`. So **IF** thread A previously set `flag=true` then we know that `i` must equal `7`: Transitivity: `i=7` "happens before" `flag=true`, and the write to `volatile flag`, *IF IT HAPPENED AT ALL*, "happens before" a read of the same `flag`.

**IF IT HAPPENED AT ALL**

Data Races and Race Conditions

The biggest thing to remember is that when the JLS promises that A "happens before" B, they are not saying that A always actually does happen before B: They are saying that you can depend on that transitive relationship. They are saying that *if* A actually did happen before B, then all of the things that "happens before" A must also have actually happened before B.

The program can print "Bleah!" because nothing prevents thread B from testing the `flag` before thread A sets it.  Some people call that a "data race." The two threads are "racing" to see which one gets to the `flag` first, and the outcome of the program depends on which thread wins that race.

When the correctness of a program depends on the outcome of a data race, some of us call that a "race condition," and that's a real headache. There's no guarantee that a program with a race condition won't do the right thing a thousand times during your testing, and then do the wrong thing when it matters most for your customer.

Answer (score 5):

[happens-before is clearly defined in the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), start by reading that; to begin with.

Then to fully understand what is going on you need to know what [Program order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3) is, as well as [synchronization order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4).

To put it very simplified, look at the below:

```
private volatile static int a = 0;
private static int b = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            b = 100;
            a = 10;
        }
    });


    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(a == 10){
                System.out.println(b);
            }

        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}
```

The only guarantee you have is that if, and only if, `t2` prints something, it will always be `100`. This is because `t2` has *seen* a `volatile write` to `a`. That happens because a "happens-before" has been established, from the writing thread to the reading one, and every action done before `a = 10` is guaranteed to be visible to the thread that has seen that `a` being `10`.

Comment: Because hb(b=100, a=10) because they're actions in the same thread in that program order (rule 1), and `a == 10` implies hb(a=10, t2), which means hb(b=100, t2) from rule 4 - right?

Comment: @daniu yes, but of course you need to stay in proper bounds of the `JLS`. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527237/java-memory-model-a-jls-statement-about-sequential-consistency-seems-incorrect/65546051#65546051) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65016214/1059372) is where I only _scrapped_ the surface of it. But really had fun.